# How can i use multi controller in one page?

Tags: yii2

How can I use multi controller in one page?
I used:

```
Yii::$app->controller->action();
```

How can I access another controllers?

Comment: Maybe runAction() is what you need: [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-module.html#runAction()-detail)

Comment: You should not do that. Better solution is move functionality that you wanna use to some component/utility class. By doing this that way you'll be able to run this function across all application.

Comment: I want to use PostController actions in every page, how can i use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new class and put your actions in the calass, after that create a object in the page you want to use it.

for example:

```
$object = new fontend\controllers\NewClassName;

$object -> YourAction();
```